# Attribute rule to union buffers

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, attribute-rules

I've successfully created an attribute rule to add a new buffer to a polygon feature class (FC) when a new point is added to a point FC. However, now I need to dissolve all buffers in the polygon FC (named "bufferTest" in code snippet below) whenever a new buffer is added. Not sure if I need to add this to the attribute rule on the point FC, or create a second attribute rule on the polygon FC. The Arcade code to create the buffer is below. How can I union/dissolve all of the buffers into a single feature?

```
var bufferDetect = BufferGeodetic($feature, 0.5, "miles")

return {
    edit: [{
        className: "bufferTest",
        adds: [{geometry: bufferDetect}]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Are you saying every time someone adds a point the buffer that is created is dissolved into any existing overlapping buffer polygons?

Comment: Exactly, the buffer is added and immediately dissolved into the other buffers, so there would be just a single feature in the buffer FC.

Comment: Unless I missed it I do not think there is a Dissolve method in the[ geometry functions](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/) of Arcade?